# How to modify the display information after user log in?

Tags: linux, debian

I want to modify the display information after user login. I know I can modify the `/etc/motd` file to change the information, but it still displays the last login time even I delete all text in `/etc/motd` file.

[image: Screenshot]

I would prefer no information after user log in.

Answer (score 1):

This information comes from the `lastlog` PAM module.  In `/etc/pam.d/login`, you'll see

```
# Prints the last login info upon succesful login
# (Replaces the `LASTLOG_ENAB' option from login.defs)
session    optional   pam_lastlog.so

# Prints the message of the day upon succesful login.
# (Replaces the `MOTD_FILE' option in login.defs)
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional   pam_motd.so
```

Adding `silent` to the end of the `pam_lastlog.so` line should stop that message being printed.

A more brutal approach would be to comment out the line completely, but that will fail to update your `wtmp` file and is probably best avoided.

`pam_lastlog` has a man page; consult it for full detail.

Answer (score 0):

The last login information is not shown by/from motd, it's printed by the login command. If you wish to suppress it, create a file called .hushlogin in your home directory:

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```